How do I setup baserow such that I can migrate data from one table to another?
I am new to base row and I would want to set up a system such that a record added to one table is automatically copied to another table.
I can't really go into too much detail but for example, once someone pays for the service I would want the user data to be copied to another table where the payment ID of the user is concatenated with the last 3 characters of their name and that is saved as the user ID.
Likewise, I had an idea to use a lambda script, but that logic makes no sense.
I have tried writing a python script that accesses the base row API to copy data from table 1, but the script does not access the other table.
Here is some code:
import os
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Fetch data from the database
    data = fetch_data_from_database()

    # Write the data to Baserow
    write_to_baserow(data)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }

def fetch_data_from_database():
    url = "https://base.example.com/api/database/rows/table/666/?user_field_names=true"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Token {os.environ['DATABASE_TOKEN']}"
    }

    try:
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data from the database: {e}")
        raise

    # Extract the relevant fields
    results = []
    for item in data['results']:
        results.append({
           # Sensitive data
          
          })

    return results

def write_to_baserow(data):
    baserow_url = os.environ['BASEROW_URL']
    baserow_api_key = os.environ['BASEROW_API_KEY']
    destination_table_id = os.environ['DESTINATION_TABLE_ID']

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Token {baserow_api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    url = f"{baserow_url}/api/database/rows/table/{destination_table_id}/"          
    for row in data:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=row)
        response.raise_for_status()              

